# Why isn't detox any faster than tox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, tox

I've cached my dependencies in the appropriate folder - `.tox/pyX/...` and run both:

```
time detox
time tox
```

in that order. The results I get are:

```
real    0m35.923s
user    0m38.696s
 sys    0m31.619s
```

and

```
real    0m39.385s
user    0m20.149s
 sys    0m19.779s
```

Shouldn't `detox` be four times faster than `tox`, given that I am testing four different python versions in parallel rather than in series?

My tox file is as follows:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = py27,py34,py35,py36
[testenv]
commands =
  pip install .
  py.test
  publish: python setup.py sdist upload --sign -r pypi
```

Example from Circle:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea, but I would recommend to open an issue [here](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues) with a detox prefix and either link to the concrete project or provide a minimal reproducer. I don't use detox myself (yet), but I would be surprised, if this would be the general case - so you must trigger some kind of corner case.